# WHERE clause not working in a query - Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, zend-framework, where-clause

I set up a simple DB in MySQL with these informations:

[image: My DB in phpmyadmin]

And a Zend Model CalendarioVeicolo to interact with the DB.

In my Controller file, if I execute the following query:

```php
$query = $model->select()
    ->where('start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', $innerDate, $innerDate);
```

All works out fine and the output is this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-10-17 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-18 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-19 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-20 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 15, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 16, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 17, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 18, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 19, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 20, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-21 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 9, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 10, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 11, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 12, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 13, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 14, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 15, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 16, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 17, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 18, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 19, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}},
            { "reference": 20, "value": { "id": "17", "veicolo": "Renault Megane"}}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-22 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-23 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, for the 2022-10-20 date it return a reservation after 14:00.

But if I try to add a WHERE clause on the vehicle (`veicolo` column), like so:

```
$query = $model->select()
    ->where('veicolo = ? AND start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', $vehicle, $innerDate, $innerDate);
```

The result is a void JSON:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-10-17 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-18 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-19 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-20 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-21 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-22 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
   },
    {
        "date": "2022-10-23 00:00:00",
        "value": [
            { "reference": 8, "value": []},
            { "reference": 9, "value": []},
            { "reference": 10, "value": []},
            { "reference": 11, "value": []},
            { "reference": 12, "value": []},
            { "reference": 13, "value": []},
            { "reference": 14, "value": []},
            { "reference": 15, "value": []},
            { "reference": 16, "value": []},
            { "reference": 17, "value": []},
            { "reference": 18, "value": []},
            { "reference": 19, "value": []},
            { "reference": 20, "value": []}
        ]
    }
]
```

I checked the vehicle value and is working, is a correct integer.

The same query with the WHERE clause in phpmyadmin return a correct result with a reservation for the vehicle 1 on 2022-10-20 after 14:00, in contrast with the void JSON.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but the JSON is hardly readable, I guess nobody wants to scroll through a 1-liner and visually check for differences... can you please elaborate and give a more concrete hint about the issue? Furthermore, since it's a database related problem, you'd preferably post a minimal reproducible example (schema, database values, queries)

Comment: @Niccolò I formatted the data for you, because it was really unreadable. Still, there is too much useless stuff in there, so consider to remove it to make it more readable for other users.

Comment: Besides that, there is something missing here. You show a table (8 columns, 3 rows), but you query pops out a series of date that **are not in the table**, and you also show unlisted data (where does _Renault Megane_ comes from?). As said by @HonkderHase, it would be better to post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: PS: the "vehicle" ids are shown as `string` (`"id": "17"` instead of `"id": 17`). Are you sure to have declared them correctly in all tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your where is incorrectly formed. It should be:

```
$query = $model->select()
    ->where('start_date <= ?', $innerDate);
    ->where('end_date >= ?', $innerDate);
```

The `where` method only supports one replacement parameter. ([see code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Select.php#L1023)) Third parameter is type, not another value. It also supports quoting array, but only in format `where('x IN (?)', $arrayOfValues)` I believe.

Alternatively you can quote yourself

```
$where = sprintf(
  'start_date <= %s AND end_date >= %s', 
  $db->quote($innerDate), 
  $db->quote($innerDate)
);
$query = $model->select()
    ->where($where)
```